# How can I control the group by behavior?

Tags: mysql, group-by

I want to get all stage,class,status for an event. The problem is that some stages have several rows:

```
mysql> select stage,class,status from results where event=3009 and person=81451;
+-------+-------+-----------+
| stage | class | status    |
+-------+-------+-----------+
|  3210 | 52800 | OK        |
|  3209 | 52800 | Cancelled |
|  3208 | 52800 | OK        |
|  3209 | 52798 | OK        |
+-------+-------+-----------+
4 rows in set (0,01 sec)
```

I only one want row per stage. So my idea was to use group by:

```
mysql> select stage,class,status from results where event=3009 and person=81451 group by stage;
+-------+-------+-----------+
| stage | class | status    |
+-------+-------+-----------+
|  3208 | 52800 | OK        |
|  3209 | 52800 | Cancelled |
|  3210 | 52800 | OK        |
+-------+-------+-----------+
3 rows in set (0,00 sec)
```

But in the case of several rows I want the status=OK row to be selected. How can I do that?

The result I WANT to end up with is:

```
+-------+-------+-----------+
| stage | class | status    |
+-------+-------+-----------+
|  3208 | 52800 | OK        |
|  3209 | 52798 | OK        |
|  3210 | 52800 | OK        |
+-------+-------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 2):

since `OK` is greater than `CANCELLED` you can use `MAX()`.

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    results a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  stage, MAX(status) status
            FROM    result
            WHERE   event = 3009 
                    AND person = 81451
            GROUP   BY stage
        ) b ON  a.stage = b.stage AND
                a.status = b.status
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f9ed3/3)

Comment: if I add 'AND a.class = b.class' there I would get stage=3209 and class=52800. Expected is class=52798. So I'm still not convinced this works for me.

Comment: please give sample records that has `class`. or you can alter the fiddle link.

Comment: SELECT `stage`, `class`, MAX(status) FROM  results GROUP   BY stage
CHeck this query. I am getting the same result set and removed the inner join.

Comment: That results in class=52800 for all stages. Should be 52798 when stage=3209.